# Tricky var verification in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a variable that exists or not depending to my inputs
so i have made a if :

```
if { [info exists $var1] } {
    puts "Here we are, Born to be kings, We're the princes of the universe ..."
}
```

but when i launch my script, i get the error log :

```
can't read "var1": no such variable
while executing
"info exists $var1"
```

What's the mistake ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `if { [info exists var1] } {...`

The variables are replaced **before** the call is made, and `info` is no exception. So pass the *name* of the variable instead of it's value.

Comment: I think we need a wiki page for that matter. The things you pointed out in your second answer on the other question are really helpful, and when I started with Tcl, it took a while get this concept, but now I love it.